# How to get a string value in input as invalid?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been playing around with strings and I've found that when one inputs a string into a input function it gives an error.

I was wondering how to `print "invalid"` if a string was typed for an `input` variable. I want to do this the simplest way possible and the function should be the input and not the raw_input and I don't want to use `try` or `except` because that would complicate the code I'm planning to create.

```
testing_variable = input ("enter a number:")
# if a string is entered print invalid
if testing_variable == "":
# the "" is what im using if a string is entered and im having a hard time solving this 
#Tips or advice of any coversion of the input would be helpful 
    print "invalid"
```

Comment: FYI in python3 input() is the same as raw_input() in python2

Comment: I don't understand how anything else could be clearer and less complicated than try/except for conversions. `int()` has to fail if given a non-integer and the way failures are communicated in Python is via exceptions; every other way is more complicated,

Answer (score 2):

Python 2.7 supports `input` and `raw_input`.

So, with `input`, you are expected to wrap your input with quotes. If you are wanting to avoid this, then use raw_input.

Example with raw_input:

```
>>> raw_input('hi ')
hi hey
'hey'
```

If you are looking to force the user to always enter a digit, then you can wrap it in a try/except as such:

```
try:
    i = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
except:
    print("you did not enter a number")
```

Comment: yeap i was wondering if there is any way to convert a string when typed in into a input function to out invalid

Comment: is this only for raw_input because i wanted to show if a string is typed in into a input variable to show invalid

Comment: Yes. Because with raw_input everything will be a string. Even if you provide a number. It will be stored as a string. So you need to do proper handling to check what it is.

Comment: if it was a raw_input would one convert it into an integer by using int()?

Comment: Yes, for raw_input you will have to cast it to int.

Comment: does that also work is the raw_input is a string for example : int("hello") is that now an integer?

Comment: That is the point of using the try/except. If you try to do int("some_string") it will raise and fall in to the except block. Look at my updated example with the try/except I did. If you try to do int("some_string") it will do `print("you did not enter a number")`

Answer (score 2):

Using the `input` function in Python 2 is generally a bad idea. It is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`, and thus expects the user to input a valid Python expression. If they type in something that is not valid Python, you'll always get an error.

While you could catch various exceptions and translate them into useful error messages, a better approach is to use `raw_input` and do your own validation for the specific types of input you want to be able to handle. If you only want to accept numbers, try converting the string you get from `raw_input` to `int` or `float` (and catching `ValueError` exceptions which indicate non-numeric input). For your desired result of printing `"invalid"`:

```
try:
    result = int(raw_input("enter a number"))
except ValueError:
    print "invalid"
```

This is the most Pythonic way to solve the issue. If for some reason you don't want to use exception handling, you can save the string you get from `raw_input` and analyze it first to make sure it has only the characters you expect before converting it to a number. For base 10 integers this is not too hard, as only digits need to be checked for, and the `isdigit` method on a string will check if it contains only digit charaters:

```
str_input = raw_input("enter a number")
if str_input.isdigit():
    result = int(str_input)
else: # string contains non-digit characters
    print "invalid"
```

It's quite a bit more complicated to validate the input string if you want to support floating point numbers, as there's no convenient function like `isdigit` that will check all the characters for you. You could do it if you really wanted to, but I'd strongly recommend going with the exception catching code style shown above and just passing the string to `float` to see if it works.

Comment: is there also a way where only numbers can be typed in while any letter typed in should show invalid but with the function input ()

Comment: There's no way to validate what a user types into an `input()` prompt before Python tries interpreting it as a Python expression. They can type in something like `x+5` and if you have an `x` variable defined with an value that you can add 5 to, it will work. If not, it will raise an exception. If you want to do useful validation, use `raw_input`! There is no other way.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way in my opinion:

```
testing_variable = input ("enter a number:")
try:
   number_var = int(testing_variable)
   print(number_var)
except ValueError:
   print("Invalid")
```

Without using **try** you can do:

```
testing_variable = input ("enter a number:")
if not testing_variable.isdigit():
    print("Invalid")
```

Comment: i know but i prefer not to use try and except is there any other way?

Comment: Sorry, is try and except, but is the simpler and correct way.

Comment: is there a way to test if input is a letter then show invalid instead of the error statement?

Comment: I've added another answer.

Comment: 1. try ... except is the correct way in python; 2. instead of adding a new answer, edit your first one